# Show that $(a − b)(b − c)(a − c)$ is always an even integer if $a, b,$ and $c$ are integers.

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Show that $(a − b)(a − c)(b − c)$ is always even if $a, b, c$ are integers. It should be solved with the pigeonhole principle but I could not find a solution.

Comment: How many of the factors can be odd?

Comment: Hint: a product of integers is even if any of the factors multiplied together is even.

Comment: HINT: It suffices to show that at least one of the three factors is even. Consider the sum of the three factors.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics StackExchange, Mademado!  Some people (not me) have started downvoting this, probably because you haven't explained what you've already tried.  You know that it should involve the pigeonhole principle, which involves counting things and matching them with other things, so what kinds of things have you considered counting and matching?  Even if you got nowhere, tell use what you tried, and we can reply better.

Answer (score 0):

If a, b and c are odd or even it is obvius that difference between each pair is even number.

If there are two odd numbers and an even number, the difference between the odd numbers is even.

If there are two even numbers and an odd number, the difference between the even numbers is even.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Remember that when adding/multiplying integers,

- $\text{even} \pm \text{even} = \text{even}$
- $\text{odd} \pm \text{odd} = \text{even}$
- $\text{even} \pm \text{odd} = \text{odd}$
- $\text{even} \times \text{even} = \text{even}$
- $\text{even} \times \text{odd} = \text{even}$
- $\text{odd} \times \text{odd} = \text{odd}$